# ax.set_xticks causing figure to shrink

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot topographic figure using Cartopy and Matplotlib. The data were downloaded [here](https://topex.ucsd.edu/cgi-bin/get_data.cgi) which contains three columns of data: longitude, latitude, and depth (or elevation from sea surface since the numbers are negative).

The figure looks fine only without the xticks when I turn off ax.set_xticks(). Once I turned on ax.set_xticks(), the figure suddenly shrinks.

What I don't really understand is why ax.set_xticks is causing this while the yticks works just fine.

## xticks off:

[image: xticks off]

## xticks on:

[image: xticks on]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

#import the data from local file
df=pd.read_csv('latlon_coor.csv')
df.columns=['longitude','latitude','depth']

Lonmin,Lonmax = min(df.longitude), max(df.longitude)
Latmin,Latmax = min(df.latitude), max(df.latitude)
pts=1000

#Some points to be shown on figure
#station AXBA1
AXBlat,AXBlon = 45.820179, -129.736694
#station HYSB1
HYSlat,HYSlon = 44.509781, -125.405296
#Portland for reference
Ptllat,Ptllon = 45.523064, -122.676483
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
extent = [Lonmin, Lonmax, Latmin,Latmax]

#Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8), dpi=80, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
ax.set_extent(extent)

ax.plot(AXBlon, AXBlat, 'b*',label='AXBA1',markersize=20)
ax.plot(HYSlon, HYSlat, 'r*',label='HYSB1',markersize=20)
ax.plot(Ptllon, Ptllat, 'k*',label='Portland',markersize=20)
ax.text(AXBlon-0.7, AXBlat+0.2, 'AXBA1',fontsize = 25)
ax.text(HYSlon-0.7, HYSlat+0.2, 'HYSB1',fontsize = 25)
ax.text(Ptllon-0.7, Ptllat+0.2, 'Portland',fontsize = 25)

#Adding the topography layer
[x,y] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(Lonmin, Lonmax, pts),
                    np.linspace(Latmin, Latmax, pts))
z = griddata((df.longitude, df.latitude), df.depth, (x, y), method='linear');
x = np.matrix.flatten(x); #Gridded longitude
y = np.matrix.flatten(y); #Gridded latitude
z = np.matrix.flatten(z); #Gridded elevation
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
ax.scatter(x,y,1,z,cmap='terrain')

#adding features to map
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES)
ax.gridlines()
ax.coastlines()
#ax.set_title('Area of Interest', fontsize=25)
#ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(Lonmin, Lonmax, 5))
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(Latmin, Latmax, 5))
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude [°]', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude [°]', rotation=0, fontsize=15, labelpad=50)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don’t believe you can directly manipulate axes ticks using cartopy: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.13/matplotlib/gridliner.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seems that I can draw the latitudes and longitudes using cartopy attributes rather than matplotlib attributes? That's definitely a way to work through. But this still does not explain why, in my code, the yticks works well but the sticks does not.